# WebStorm — 'unresolved function or method' express.get warning

Tags: mocha.js, warnings, webstorm

WebStorm can't resolve a function from several modules. For example, it can't resolve `get` method from `express` module or `toBe` from `expect` module.

```
const expect = require('expect')
const mocha = require('mocha')
const describe = mocha.describe
const it = mocha.it

const utils = require('./utils')

describe('Utils', () => {
    describe('#add', () => {
        it('should add two numbers', () => {
            let res = utils.add(33, 11)
            expect(res).toBe(44).toBeA('number')
        })

        it('should async add two numbers', (done) => {
            utils.asyncAdd(4, 3, (err, sum) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                expect(sum).toBe(7).toBeA('number')
                done()
            })
        })
    })
})
```

For `mocha` elements I solved by adding `it` and `describe` functions separately. But don't see any solution for other.

Can these functions be resolved? If not, is there a solution how to suppress only these warnings without adding a comment to the code?

Answer (score 4):

Express methods are generated dynamically in runtime, so they can't be resolved during static code analysis. Installing TypeScript stubs would make things better: put cursor on `'express'` in `const express = require('express');` and hit `Alt+Enter` to install typings:

[image]

Typings installing should also help with `expect` methods resolving

Comment: So it is kinda workaround, because it can't help with pure JS. What I want to find that's the way hide exactly this one warning if WebStorm can't resolve this function. But thank you anyway, I will try this one.